# Is there any open technology to recognize face features?

Tags: image-processing, face-recognition

I need to make baby face depending on parents' photos. Something like: http://www.makemebabies.com/

It may be not very advanced and may just try to recognize, for example, eyes from constant set  of eyes variants in database. The main feature is to set up it at own server.

Is there any open-source or not-so-expensive solutions?

Comment: Are you looking for a program that already does this, or an API to program against?

Comment: Open source and not-so-expensive solutions for setting up a server or to "make baby face"?

Comment: to recognize descrete parts of face, I guess

Comment: Yep, to recognize descrete parts of face. I could do other stuff by myself. But if it's ready to use — why not?

Answer (score 8):

Check out [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/).

Open-source: Yes
Not-so-expensive: Yes

Comment: Man. The only thing more amazing than needing to do this with OSS in the first place is the fact that there is actually OSS in existence that *does* it. And it makes me feel a very small cog in these internets indeed.

Comment: I've seen that. Nedd to take a closer look to decide if it fits my needs

Comment: Who are you, @JungleHunter ? You ask (and answer) wonderfully clever questions. Your profile content is charmingly opaque. Where can I find more about your work? I'll delete this if it is intrusive.

Comment: @FeralOink Haha! Okay, but that doesn't tell much either. Anyway, this isn't the place for conversation. So I'll tweet to you.